# get data from json based on index number in flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a json file from where I am collecting only email addresses, and want to print index number base output like 3rd record's email address to Text widget..

```
class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  List<String> list = [];

  Future<List<String>> getcomments() async {
    Uri url =
        Uri.parse('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1/comments');
    var response = await http.get(url);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var jsondata = json.decode(response.body);

      list.clear();
      for (var jdata in jsondata) {
        list.add(jdata['email']);
      }
    }
    return list;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('JSON'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: FutureBuilder(
          future: getcomments(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            return Text(snapshot.data[2].toString());
            //here i want only 3rd data(index 2)
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: can you post your result

Comment: showing an error Error: The operator '[]' isn't defined for the class 'Object?'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this?

```
FutureBuilder(
      future: getcomments(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        List<String> data = snapshot.data as List<String>;
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return const CircularProgressIndicator();
        }
        else {
          return Text(data[2]);
        }
      },
    ),
```

Comment: also you should not forget the loading state when using futurebuilder

Comment: if I can use a statement like snapshot.data[index] inside a list view.builder, y it is not working with Text(snapshot.data[2])...this made me confused